# Prove that a certain function $\varphi:[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $[a,b]\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $\varphi:[a,b]\to\mathbb{C}$ be continuous such that $|\varphi(t)|\leq M$ for all $t \in [a,b]$ where $M>0$. We have to prove that if $\left| \displaystyle\int_a^b \varphi(t)\space dt \right| = M(b-a)$ then $\varphi(t)=c$, where $c\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|c|=M$.

So far I have only got that if $\varphi$ is a constant function and let $\varphi (t)=c$ then:

$\left| \displaystyle\int_a^b \varphi(t)\space dt \right| = \left| \displaystyle\int_a^b c\space dt \right| = |c|\left| \displaystyle\int_a^b dt \right| = |c||b-a|=|c|(b-a)=M(b-a)$ which implies $|c|=M$.

However, I don't know how to prove that $\varphi$ is constant. I would thank you a lot if you could give me some hints on this. Please don't give me the full solution, just small hints.

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a hint. What's the maximum value of $\left|\int_a^b f(t)\,dt\right|$ out of all functions $f$ such that $|f(t)|\leq M$? Assume $b > a$.

Comment: Here's another hint. The inequality $|\int_a^b f(t)\,dt|\le \int_a^b |f(t)|dt$ is a generalization of the triangle inequality. *When does equality hold* in the triangle inequality? When does it hold for the integral case?

Comment: It's easy to show that $|\varphi|\equiv M$, but that just means $\varphi(t)=Me^{ig(t)}$ for some continuous function $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$. I forget how to deal with that situation.  Can we extend $\varphi$ to a bounded entire function and apply Liouville?

Comment: @BenW: There's nothing holomorphic/analytic in this question. We just have a continuous complex-valued function.

Answer (score 1):

First let's assume $\displaystyle\int_a^b \varphi(t)\space dt \ = M(b-a)$ where $|\phi(t)| \le M$.

Then $\Re \phi(t) \le M$ and  by taking the real part in the integral above, we get $\displaystyle\int_a^b \Re\varphi(t)\space dt \ = M(b-a)$ hence $\displaystyle\int_a^b (M-\Re\varphi(t))\space dt \ = 0$. But the integrand is non-negative, hence it is zero a.e, hence by continuity it is zero everywhere, so $\Re \phi(t) =M$ and since $|\phi(t)| \le M$, it follows $\Im \phi(t)=0$ and $|\phi(t)|=\phi(t)=M$

In the general case we know that $\displaystyle\int_a^b \varphi(t)\space dt \ = e^{i\theta}M(b-a)$ for some argument $\theta$, hence $\displaystyle\int_a^b \psi(t)\space dt \ = M(b-a)$, where $\psi(t)=e^{-i\theta}\phi(t)$ satisfies the same hypotheis (continuity, modulus bound) as $\phi$ hence by the previous case $\psi(t)=M, \phi(t)=e^{i\theta}M$ and we are done!